# `exec env` vs `env`

Tags: environment-variables, ps, exec

Both `exec` and `env` don't fork, see the following example:

```bsh
docker run --rm -it ubuntu:18.04 sh -c 'exec sleep 1 & ps -Ho pid,ppid,cmd'
```

```
  PID  PPID CMD
    1     0 sh -c exec sleep 1 & ps -Ho pid,ppid,cmd
    7     1   sleep 1
    8     1   ps -Ho pid,ppid,cmd
```

```bsh
docker run --rm -it ubuntu:18.04 sh -c 'env sleep 1 & ps -Ho pid,ppid,cmd'
```

```
  PID  PPID CMD
    1     0 sh -c env sleep 1 & ps -Ho pid,ppid,cmd
    7     1   sleep 1
    8     1   ps -Ho pid,ppid,cmd
```

## Question

I see lots of people using `exec env ...` but I don't think `exec` is necessary because `env` doesn't fork just like `exec`.

Is there any use case that we need to use `exec env` instead of `env`?

Comment: `exec utility &` is an odd thing to want to do. It is the same as `utility &`.  It would be more interesting to you to compare `exec utility` (where utility may be `env`) with `env utility`, once you understand what `exec` and `env` are used for.

Comment: I know the difference between exec and env, what I want to ask is the difference between `exec env` and `env`

Comment: So you know what `exec` does then? It replaces the current process with the utility (for example `env`).  `env` does not do that by itself, it just runs the utility. That's the difference.  You can't test that with a background process in the way you are showing though.  Instead of `sleep 1`, use `sh -c 'sleep 1'`.

Comment: exec prevents the shell to fork (unless used with `&` which nobody does). Else fork is always involved: done by the shell.

Comment: @they I don't understand, env just run the utility by....execvp? https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/env.c#L894

Comment: @WeihangJian Yes? I don't know what your question is any longer. `env` is an external utility that executes some other utility, possibly with a modified environment. `exec` is a _shell built-in utility_ which replaces the current shell with some other process. I don't quite know where your confusion comes from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`env` (probably) doesn't itself fork, just replaces itself with the program it does. But that's different from the parent shell forking off `env`, or just replacing itself with `env`.

E.g. compare these two:

```
$ bash -c 'env ls > /dev/null; echo hi'
hi
$ bash -c 'exec env ls > /dev/null; echo hi'
[no output]
```

With `exec`, the shell itself is replaced, and the following `echo` doesn't run.

Of course, you had `exec env ... &` instead. With `&`, the shell forks anyway to start the background process, and it might not fork *again* to run the single command within the background task. At least Bash optimizes cases like that, e.g.:

```
$ bash -c 'ps -Ho pid,ppid,cmd; echo x'
  PID  PPID CMD
11967  1545 -/bin/bash
14851 11967   bash -c ps -Ho pid,ppid,cmd; echo x
14852 14851     ps -Ho pid,ppid,cmd
x
$ bash -c 'ps -Ho pid,ppid,cmd'
  PID  PPID CMD
11967  1545 -/bin/bash
14853 11967   ps -Ho pid,ppid,cmd
```

where the latter doesn't show the in-between `bash` process, the behaviour is the same as if there was an `exec` there. (`-/bin/bash` is my interactive shell.)

Bash only does that for an alone command, if there are more than one, the shell waits for the last one to exit. Using `exec` there would make a difference:

```
$ bash -c 'echo x; ps -Ho pid,ppid,cmd'
x
  PID  PPID CMD
11967  1545 -/bin/bash
14929 11967   bash -c echo x; ps -Ho pid,ppid,cmd
14930 14929     ps -Ho pid,ppid,cmd
$ bash -c 'echo x; exec ps -Ho pid,ppid,cmd'
x
  PID  PPID CMD
11967  1545 -/bin/bash
14933 11967   ps -Ho pid,ppid,cmd
```

With `&`, this would be the same with `exec ps`:

```
$ bash -c 'ps -Ho pid,ppid,cmd & sleep 1'
  PID  PPID CMD
11967  1545 -/bin/bash
14867 11967   bash -c ps -Ho pid,ppid,cmd & sleep 1
14868 14867     ps -Ho pid,ppid,cmd
14869 14867     sleep 1
```

But with a compound block, we see the background shell process too:

```
$ bash -c '{ ps -Ho pid,ppid,cmd; } & sleep 1'
  PID  PPID CMD
11967  1545 -/bin/bash
14877 11967   bash -c { ps -Ho pid,ppid,cmd; } & sleep 1
14878 14877     bash -c { ps -Ho pid,ppid,cmd; } & sleep 1
14880 14878       ps -Ho pid,ppid,cmd
14879 14877     sleep 1
```

---

You didn't give any specific sources for the those lots of people doing `exec env`, so we don't know their exact situation. But you'd use `exec env` the same way as `exec anyprogram`: if you want to replace the shell with some other process. E.g. this mock example:

```
#!/bin/bash
. someconfigfile
if [ "$someconfig" = blah ]; then
    exec env myprogram some args...
    echo "failed to start" >&2
    exit 1
elif
    ... whatever
fi
```

The `exec` there replaces the script with the launched program, so that the shell doesn't remain in memory uselessly. Also if the script there is just an intermediary to start the program, doing an `exec` will keep the PID the same, which makes it easier for the parent (of the script and then the program) to monitor its child.